# How to run specific gradle task only if this given test was activated at gradle test phase?

Tags: gradle

I want to make sure that a particular gradle task is running before tests only if specific tests is enabled.

For instance, let's say I have test called TranslationTests that look something like this:

```
@EnabledIfSystemProperty(named = "org.shabunc.tests.TranslationTests", matches = "true")
class TranslationTests {
  ...
}
```

Which is activated the following way:

```
test {
  if (project.hasProperty(projectProperty)) {
            systemProperty(projectProperty, "org.shabunc.tests.TranslationTests")
  }
}
```

Now I want to be sure that each time I'm running:

```
gradle test -Porg.shabunc.tests.TranslationTests
```

before tests some specific gradle task, say `gradle prepareTranslationSetup` is triggered. Strictly speaking I want this task to be triggered each time I know TranslationTests are running - and don't be triggered otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onlyIf()` on task `prepareTranslationSetup` and make `test` depend on it. `onlyIf()` is defined as follows:

> You can use the `onlyIf()` method to attach a predicate to a task. The task’s actions are only executed if the predicate evaluates to true.

(From: [Authoring Tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:using_a_predicate))

### Example

Let's say you've got the following tasks:

```
task doBeforeTest {
    onlyIf {
        project.hasProperty("runit")
    }

    doLast {
        println "doBeforeTest()"
    }
}

task runTest {
    dependsOn = [ doBeforeTest ]

    doLast {
        println "runTest()"
    }
}
```

`doBeforeTest`'s actions are only executed if the project has the specified property. `runTest` is configured to depend on `doBeforeTest`. Now, when you do

```
gradlew runTest --info
```

the output is similar to

```
> Task :doBeforeTest SKIPPED
Skipping task ':doBeforeTest' as task onlyIf is false.

> Task :runTest
runTest()
```

As you can see `doBeforeTest` is skipped as the precondition is not fulfilled. On the other hand, running

```
gradlew runTest -Prunit
```

executes `doBeforeTest` as expected

```
> Task :doBeforeTest
doBeforeTest()

> Task :runTest
runTest()
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I believe it would be beneficial for many. However it's not exactly what I've been looking for. This way I'll have to introduce knowledge about specific flag to other tasks as well. The task will be triggered based on the value of that flag while what I'm actually looking for is the task that is triggered based on whether specific test is active or not. Most probably it's impossible however this is what I'm looking for.